# Lang facade not detecting app lang change

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to change my app locale in Laravel 7 by using a configuration controller:

```
class ConfigController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *
     * Set the App locale.
     *
     * @param  \SetLocaleRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function set_locale(SetLocaleRequest $request)
    {
        App::setLocale($request->locale);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => trans('config.set'),
        ], 200);
    }
}
```

This code actually works because a simple `App:getLocale();` returns the language provided. Either way, the `Lang` facade keeps using the default locale provided at `config/app.php` which is spanish. So, this code:

```
Lang::get('auth.failed')
```

Is returning the text: `"Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros."` even though the `en` is currently selected. Any idea why?

Comment: did you try using trans helper; what does trans('auth.failed') print?

Comment: It doesn't work in my other controllers. Funny thing (look at the edited question). The message sent on the JSON response is detecting the changes with the trans helper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically changing locale is 2 steps. I see you've done step 1. Step 2 is to do something like this in your blade file (most likely the base template):

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
```

Note that once the user navigates to another page, it reverses to locale set in config. If you, however, need to maintain locale setting for the current user, use session. For example, in addition to my earlier point, change your controller method to:

```
public function set_locale(SetLocaleRequest $request)
    {
        App::setLocale($request->locale);
        Session::put('locale', $request->locale);

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'locale.set.success',
        ], 200);
    }
```

So, you can access it continuously in the blade template through: `<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', Session::get('locale')) }}">`

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm not using Laravel as a full-stack app. It is only my API. I'm using a Vuejs client that consumes that API. Does this affect the session part?

Comment: Yes it does. I assumed you're using laravel fullstack. The session idea should still work though with slight modifcation. What you just need to do is create a middleware that runs just after the middleware that authenticates user. The middleware will take the locale from session and set it on every request.

For example, if you're using jwt, call the middleware after JWT authentication so authenticated user is available in session.

Comment: What if I want to change the language at any given time? Let's say an user selects the chinese locale and now i want to receive chinese messages from my Laravel API. Should I put my controller's logic inside a middleware and protect a "set-locale" route with that middleware, changing the locale everytime I perform a POST request over it?

Comment: There are 2 ways to go about it. You either have a route that accepts locale as input, change the locale and put the locale value in session. Or you modify the locale middleware we talked about such that it checkes the request object each time to see if locale is sent. if sent, it changes the locale and puts in session so subsequent requests can get the locale from session

Comment: Did exactly as you said in that last comment (option 2) and now it works. Thanks a lot.